# inserting c# double values to sql server float field. (no fractional part)

Tags: c#, sql-server, floating-point, double, type-conversion

I am trying to insert double values to my database via EF 5. I generated EF entity model from db. There is a price column in the table which is float, and naturally EF generated a double type for the mapper class. 
I read some string values from a file and convert it to double and save it to db. When I debug I can see that values are converted correctly. For example string value `"120,53"` is converted to double like `120.53`, just fine. But when I save my context it goes to db like `"12053"`.

What can cause such a problem? Is there any setting in SQL Server has anything to do with this?

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: maybe show the lines of code where you load, convert and save the values?

Comment: My code is basicly like this.
   Product p = new Product();
   product.SalePrice = Convert.ToDouble(somestring.Replace('.', ','));
   context.Products.Add(p);
   context.SaveChanges();

Comment: I couldn't format it in comment box. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your Convert.ToDouble and the , being used instead of a decimal. Without supplying the culture for the number it's likely instead interpreting the , as a thousandths separator and ignoring it. Try passing in CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as the second argument (IFormatProvider) if the culture of your environment is one where the , is used as a decimal. Or, since it looks like you're replacing a decimal with the , - just don't replace it.